# Null Value in Kettle Group By

Tags: null, group-by, kettle

I'm using Kettle's Group By step. When Group By returns a null value for any variable, I can't do insert into MySql (gives error about "NaN"). I wrote into txt file and the value was written as "?". How can I transform this value to null? If I test the value, it isn't null.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the value is not actually `null` but is *Not a Number (NaN)*.  You could add a **Modified Java Script Value** step with the code:

```
if isNaN(field_name) {
  field_name = null;
}
```

This will see if your field is not a number, and if so set it to `null`.